# How to get workflowservicehost workflow status

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I have workflow say WF1 hosted in workflowservicehost.
Now at client side I want to fetch the status of the WF1.
Is there any way to get the status.
I don't want to use the Workflow tracking to get the status.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my view is to setup a workflow tracking participant and add it to the workflow application's extensions. The tracking participant can then provide data to another WCF service that the client can reference to get the health of the workflow.

Another approach is to setup your workflow so that it provides two web methods by using the **ReceiveAndSendReply** activities, contained in a **PickBranch** activity. One of the **Receive** activities can perform your normal operation, and the other **Receive** activity can provide the status of the workflow. This isn't a clean solution though in my opinion.